# Notepad++ range replace

Tags: python, notepad++

I'm trying to replace several hundred different values with a single value:(example)=

Line 115242:            birth_date="850.1.1"

Line 115317:            birth_date="851.1.1"

Line 115392:            birth_date="855.1.1"
.... etc.

I want to replace each one with: birth_date="451.1.1"

Is there a quick and easy way to do it with the replace function? (assume I don't know any of terms/acronyms/jargon)

Essencially, I'm trying to replace the range of values between:

birth_date="600.1.1" and birth_date="900.1.1"

This is in python

Comment: Use Python to do the replace?

Comment: Are there values in the file that are outside the range you specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to leverage regular expressions. The range limitation makes it more difficult, but with 2 different replaces, I think we can manage it. (The complication comes from the fact you don't want to replace values like `900.4.3`.)

1. Back up your file, just to be safe.
2. Open the Replace dialog, and change Search Mode to "Regular expression".
3. Enter `birth_date="[678]\d\d\.\d+\.\d+"` in "Find what:".
4. Enter `birth_date="451.1.1"` in "Replace with:"
5. Press Replace All.
6. Change "Find what:" to `birth_date="900\.1\.1"`.
7. Press Replace All.

Then check to make sure it did what you wanted. A differencing tool might be helpful there. (You can compare the modified file with the back up.)

The two different regexes are necessary because of the range. The first one catches anything starting with `6`, `7`, or `8` plus any two numeric digits. The second handles the last value we want to replace, which is the first of the `900` values.

Comment: Beautiful, it worked. though the range I specified simply covered ALL the values, there weren't any over 900 or under 600.
(is there a web page that covers WHY that works? I want to understand it so I can use it for what ever i want in the future)

Comment: Without the range limitation, you could've just used `birth_date="\d+\.\d+\.\d+"` for the find. You'll need to learn about regular expressions if you want to understand. Regular expressions are a way of specifying patterns, and then a regular expression library can use that pattern to try to match strings. They can be kind of hard to get into, but it's a good sign that you're asking "why". Here's a tutorial, if it helps: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html. You might want to seek out other resources, too, especially if that doesn't seem too clear at first.

Comment: Also, James, you may want to look at [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) which allows you to play around with regular expressions in real-time.